# No event tracking in Google Analytics

Tags: java, google-analytics, httpclient, measurement-protocol

I am sending a POST request to the Google analytics measurment protocol
at

> https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=event&tid=UA-151666808-2&cid=123&el=cus&ea=CLIENT_REGISTRATION_SUCCESS3&ec=Server

However it is not being tracked on my site. I am sending it with Java API. I use rest template, feingClient, gama-client-core, google-analytics-java libraries. The result is always the same - the event does not track.  If I change mine tid to another, then the event is displayed in another resource. Or if I call this link through POSTMAN, then the result is also successful.

Comment: What Java library are you using to?  I was not aware of any official java library for the measurement protocol.

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.coherentlogic.gama.client/gama-client-core and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.brsanthu/google-analytics-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [debug call](https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect?v=1&t=event&tid=UA-151666808-2&cid=123&el=cus&ea=CLIENT_REGISTRATION_SUCCESS3&ec=Server) for your request looks fine.

```
{
  "hitParsingResult": [ {
    "valid": true,
    "parserMessage": [ ],
    "hit": "/debug/collect?v=1\u0026t=event\u0026tid=UA-151666808-2\u0026cid=123\u0026el=cus\u0026ea=CLIENT_REGISTRATION_SUCCESS3\u0026ec=Server"
  } ],
  "parserMessage": [ {
    "messageType": "INFO",
    "description": "Found 1 hit in the request."
  } ]
}
```

## Data Processing time.

Check the real time api to ensure that the hits are being recorded if they are then you are all set. Then wait 24 - 48 hours for the data to complete processing you should see it in the standard reports then.

## bot filtering

Make sure you have disabled bot filtering on the view

[image]

## New google analytics account

It takes up to 72 hours for an account newly created in Google analytics to start showing data.

Comment: It was necessary to disable the filtering of bots in the view. Thank you

Comment: bot filtering for me too, GA will think your backend  that sends events is a bot unless you add some User-Agent header to the call, "PostmanRuntime/7.24.1" worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [google measurement protocol reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters?hl=ar#ua)

> Note that Google has libraries to identify real user agents. Hand crafting your own agent could break at any time.

You should change the request **User-Agent** to a browser like one so google doesn't think you are a bot.